# OpenCV won't save picture and not shown any error

Tags: python, opencv

This is my old code, from what I write in my short note it should read video and save each frame in a folder, I try to use it again and it's not working. There are no error shown all path exist.

```
filename = 'H2N2A'
trainingfiles = 14
def getFrames():
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('Train'+str(trainingfiles)+'/'+filename+'.MP4')
    success, image = vidcap.read()
    count = 0
    success = True
    while success:
        success, image = vidcap.read()
        #print 'Read a new frame: ', success
        print count
        #print "Train"+str(trainingfiles)+"/"+filename+"/frame%d.jpg" % count, image
        cv2.imwrite("Train"+str(trainingfiles)+"/"+filename+"/frame"+str(count)+".jpg", image)
        count += 1
    vidcap.release()
    return count-1
```

Do anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try calling the `getFrames()` function from somewhere else in your code?

Given the code above, Python will not run the logic in `getFrames` unless you call it first.

Comment: yes i call it in other python file. It had successfully print how many frame in the video too, but no folder nor image saved.

Comment: @ErlandDevona In that case, do the output directories exist? Namely, does the directory "Train14/H2N2A/" exist before you are running this code?

Comment: thank you. this is so embarrassing, I run an older version of my code without os.makedirs

Comment: @ErlandDevona No problem, glad I could help!